# Best direction to fly to minimise jet lag when flying from New Zealand to Europe

Tags: air-travel

I'm flying from New Zealand to Europe and can't decide what flights to book. Flights via the US take the same time as flights via Asia. Which ones would be best for jet lag? Does departure/arrival time matter for jet lag too?